# Can connect to device using Device API instead of Cloud API?

Tags: nest-api

I have reviewed Nest Cloud API and it's pretty nice feature.

As per their diagram, we need to connect to their Cloud API and that API connects to device.

I want to know that is there a way we can directly connect to device like device API instead of connecting through cloud API?

Please guide

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No this is not currently possible. However in the future there will be Nest Weave for in home device to device communication. Checkout this page for more info: https://developers.nest.com/documentation/weave/weave-overview